# DecisionTreeRegressor stops before having one sample per leaf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to OVERfit a decision tree. After looking carefully at the default parameters in [DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) it seems that simply calling the following code should work:

```py
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()
tree.fit(X,y)
y_pred = tree.predict(X)
```

Nevertheless, when inspecting which samples end up in each leaf, I am finding leaves with ~1000 different samples. Why would this happen? Is there any way to force the tree to overfit until all nodes in all leaves are exactly the same?

Comment: By samples you mean values of X then as long as y is same for them they will end in same leaf

Comment: No, I mean that I have different rows in X with different y values that end up in the same leaf. I don't understand why the algorithm does not continue to split them until  they are all in different leaves.